# How would I create a loading screen with a start button that leads to the rest of my app?

Tags: objective-c, ios

In my app, I would like a loading screen which has a start button, and when the user presses the start button, it displays my the actual parts of my application.

I can't use a Default.png because i need the functionality of the start button. And since my rootViewController is a tabBar, I can't simply add my screen as a subview, because then my loading screen just appears in each individual tab.

Any ideas?

Comment: so don't make your rootViewController a tabController; make it your start controller.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a new view controller and set that view controller as the root view controller. In the new view controller, create a UIImageView with the loading image and a UIButton where you want it. Then you could go in the storyboards and make the button transition to the "actual parts of [your] application".

Hope this helps!

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using storyboard?

Comment: Sure. The storyboard was only to make the transition easier. You could use this in the new root view controller: `[self presentModalViewController: actualPartOfApplicationController animated:YES];`

Comment: One downside of this approach is that the start screen stays loaded as your root view controller for the lifetime of your app.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do it. Assuming your app spends very little time in the Start Screen, I would implement it as a modal view controller that I display over the root tab view.

After you load your root tab bar view for the first time, present the Start Screen view controller *without* animations.

```
[tabBarViewController presentViewController:startViewController animated:NO completion:NULL];
```

If you do this early enough (e.g., in your app delegate's didFinishLaunching: method), the start screen will be the first thing the user sees. It's hard to say exactly where you should insert this code since you haven't said whether you are using storyboards or a default nib or loading a view manually etc.

When the button is pressed, simply dismiss the startViewController.